# how to make default value is empty, for button pop up form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I create a website, which can extract data from api, and do CRUD

now my "delete", "edit" button works fine and done

- edit button pic

[image: (pic)]

**Q: the add button, how can I make default value is empty ,I apply similar method as "edit" button, will pop up a form to fill up the new data and send (the only difference is from "edit", has the old data, and "add" button is null for the column)**

cause I done  "edit" button , I though "add" button shall be easier

- I simpler the code, but the concept is same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
   
</head>
<body>

  

  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.0.0:3000/api/product01",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
            return response.ipcs
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
        
          
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" },

        ]
      });


      table.draw()
      

      var rowData; 

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });

      
      $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var recipient = button.data('whatever');
         
          var data = rowData;
          
          // getEditData
          var modal = $(this);
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
          var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        });
      });
  


      function editRow_website(id){
        
        

            
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);

        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,

        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id
       

        
      }
      

      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {  
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        
        console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)

        confirmDelete(id) 
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.0.0:3000/api/product?id="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }


      function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("sure to delete this data？")== true) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
          deleteData(id);

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        } else{
          none
        }

      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class ="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new" onclick="AddRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" " onclick="AddRow()">Add New02</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_device_id" class="col-form-label">Device ID:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_device_id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_name" class="col-form-label">name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_name">
            </div>
            
            <!-- Additional form fields -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field1" class="col-form-label">group:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data_group">
            </div>

       


            <!-- End of additional form fields -->
            
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Send message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
    function AddRow() {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      var data = {
            "device_id": "string-test01",
            "name": "0",
            "group": "group-1",
            "ip": "192.168.0.111",
            "port": "3000",
            "ipc_enable": "false",
            "ftp_enable": "false"
        }
      $.ajax({
        url : 'http://192.168.0.0:3000/api/product01',
        type : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
        },
        success : function(result) {
          console.log("SUCCESS", result) 
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      });

    }


    function editRow(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      console.log("EDIT=====", data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.0.0:3000/api/product01",   
        type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
       
      }
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];
    
    function save() {
      var itemValue_device_id = document.getElementById("input_edit_device_id").value || "";
      var itemValue_edit_name = document.getElementById("input_edit_name").value || "";
      var itemValue_data_group = document.getElementById("input_edit_data_group").value || "";


      console.log("itemValue_device_id", itemValue_device_id, typeof(itemValue_device_id));
      console.log("itemValue_edit_name", itemValue_edit_name, typeof(itemValue_edit_name));
      console.log("itemValue_data_group", itemValue_data_group, typeof(itemValue_data_group));


      
      // document.getElementById("input_edit_data_group").val = itemValue;

      let send_Edit_API_Data = {
        device_id:itemValue_device_id,
        name:itemValue_edit_name,
        group: itemValue_data_group,


      }
      console.log("send_Edit_API_Data", send_Edit_API_Data);

      editRow(send_Edit_API_Data)
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I tried this function, but both "edit","add" button comes out empty

```
      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        
        var data = rowData;
        
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (recipient == ' ') { // Add New02 button clicked, clear form values
          inputFields.val('');
        } else { // Edit button clicked, populate form with existing values
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#id_of_input_to_set_null').val("");
```

Example:

```
$('#input_edit_device_id').val("");
```

You need to put this inside the function that opens the modal for adding new data.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your advice!! Can you elaborate how to fit this to my case, I tried urs, but not pretty work, I think I might use the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

if else with button id is simple way I to deal with this

````
      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data") {
          inputFields.val("");
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });

```

but still thank all you guys effort and suggestion
````